# How to implement this formula into pandas dataframe's column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, formula

How to implement ***3 Days average Sales %*** formula into pandas datafram's column_

I have a dataframe_

```
No   Sale     3 Day Average Sale %
1    4786   
2    7546   
3    2578   
4    6974     ( (No4 - ((No3+NO2+No1)/3)) / ((No3+NO2+No1)/3) ) * 100
```

Comment: just simply make use of `iloc[]` or `loc[]` accessor

Comment: I think what OP wants is a rolling average with a custom function

Comment: If I use iloc[] or loc[] then the same value printed into hole column

Comment: "I think what OP wants is a rolling average with a custom function" sir i can't understand what is you trying to tell me can you please elaborate

Comment: `df['Sale'].pct_change(3)*100`?

Comment: Is that the whole dataframe or just a sample @Scarlet

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling 4 elements at a time and apply a custom function

```
def average_sale_percent(x):
    three_day_avg = sum(x[:3]) / 3
    return ((x[3] - three_day_avg) / three_day_avg) * 100

df.Sale.rolling(4).apply(average_sale_percent)
```